# Cannot find debugging option with gradle buildship eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle

I am trying to debug a simple Ratpack application with gradle. I have gradle build builship plugin with my eclipse mars. I am just not able to find how I could debug a gradle based java application. Any help in this regard is really appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a note from Gradle community that the are still working on gradle debug plugin.

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-buildship-plugin-with-eclipse-hard-time-finding-debug-option/15325